# How to pass array in the url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, query-string

I'd like to filter and want to pass an array to the url.

```
handleFilter = (search, page = 1) => {

        const requestOption = {
            method: "GET"
        };

        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/home?search=" + JSON.stringify(search) + "&page=" + page, requestOption)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => (
                this.setState({
                    data
                })
            ))
    };
```

Just want to pass the array of data to the api to call the query

Comment: in your backend parse and convert that string to array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will be what exactly you need, but I would...
a.) Join it on a strange character, and pass it as a string. 
b.) On the receiving side (client or server), split on that same character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want send it exactly as GET method (not Post), you can form your URL like this:

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/home?search[]=value1&search[]=value2&search[]=value3"
```

That is if you don't want send JSON string.

And what the problem with JSON version or POST method?